# O que são os termos RISC e CISC em relação ao desenvolvimento de software?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-computadores

Meu professor mencionou os dois termos RISC e CISC, eles me parece ser algum tipo de arquitetura. E os softwares que são desenvolvidos (compilados) para computadores que utilizam RISC não podem ser executados em computadores do tipo CISC, mesmo utilizando sistemas operacionais iguais, ainda sim, não poderiam ser executados.

Assim sendo, eu tenho algumas dúvidas referente aos termos RISC e CISC e ao desenvolvimento de softwares para essas arquiteturas.

---

## Dúvidas

1. O que são os termos RISC e CISC?
2. Porque um software compilado para CISC não pode ser executado em um
   computador RISC ou vice e versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao desenvolvimento muito pouco. São tipos de arquiteturas diferentes. Hoje esta distinção é mais nebulosa, um mesmo processador acaba tendo as duas formas.

Não é nem que o executável não pode mudar de um modelo para outro, é que não pode mudar de uma arquitetura específica para outra já que o conjunto de instruções é completamente outro. um ARM e um MIPS são RISC e não pode transportar entre eles.

CISC ([Complex instruction set computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computer)) que é a forma mais comum de uso do Intel é caracterizado por ter instruções mais macros que executam coisas de forma um pouco mais abstrata em geral consumindo vários ciclos de *clock*. Tendem a produzir executável um pouco menos, mas com performance menos previsível. Geralmente tem um consumo extra de processamento interno, não o processamento do seu código, o que pode consumir mais energia, gerar mais aquecimento e costuma ser mais complicado programar no seu Assembly. Mas pode ter algumas facilidades também, e ter alguns ganhos de processamento específicos.

RISC ([Reduced instruction set computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computer)) cujo maior representante hoje em dia é o ARM possue instruções muito simples que faz o mínimo necessário, por isso geram executáveis maiores, ainda que já seja possível otimizar isto, e tem um processamento mais previsível. Por ter menos abstrações é mais simples programar nele. As abstrações são deixadas para outro nível. Esta simplicidade se dá porque as instruções são sempre do mesmo tamanho e o processador não tem que lidar com isto.

Uma das características bem diferente é [como a comunicação com a memória é feita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture).

Só importa para o desenvolvimento quando está programando em Assembly, mesmo assim tangencialmente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).